# 16.04 equivalent for snap assist

Tags: windows-10, window

16.04's multiple desktops and its (half screen) [snap-assist](https://m.windowscentral.com/how-use-snap-assist-windows-10-0) like features made it easy to migrate from Windows.  That being said: Is there a **simple** configuration change that would allow a window that has been 'snapped' to 1/2 of the display to be further snapped to 1/4 of the display (as found in Windows-10)?

Again, simple is better.  Thank you

Comment: Hello, as a reminder, please feel free to accept the answer if this one suits you. Otherwise I would be glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the **[Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/)** GNOME Shell extensions